# How to block a slide if the user didn't answer correctly to a question?

Tags: slideshows

I'm working on a presentation for educational purpose, every 3 slides there are some questions and the user can't see the next slide if the answers are wrong. 
I'm using Mathemtica 12! Is there a way to do that? thanks in advice!

Comment: Could you give an example of your code?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no real API for the slideshow mechanic. It would be helpful if you could add more detail to your question to explain how you are distributing these slides, what version of Mathematica you are on, and so on.

Comment: I'm using Mathematica 12, i need the slides for a presentation about education in high school through mathematica

Comment: As @CarlLange mentioned slideshows are just slideshows, if you want fancy interaction you need to explain what is your final goal, what else do you need that is not covered by built-in features, what is the context - who and how is going to use it etc etc. Otherwise any attempt to answer can fail as not exactly what you wanted. p.s. "slides for a presentation"  is hardly an explanation because this is what slideshow does anyway.

Comment: You have to control the execution of `FrontEndTokenExecute[NotebookObject[ ..], "ScrollPageNext"]`.  The token `"ScrollPageNext"` appears in three places in the file `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
  "TextResources", "MiscExpressions.tr"}]` (search for the token or `"SlideshowToolbar"`).  It also appears in `Options[EvaluationNotebook[]]` as one of the `NotebookEventActions`.  I don't know if those are all the ways a user can advance to the next slide, but I couldn't think of any others.  Someone will have to figure out how to hack all these entry points...